# how to write a class take a function as parameters in scala

Tags: scala

I have a function, how to make this function as a parameter for ServicesImpl class?

```
def blacklist: List[String] = {
    ***
  }
```

```
class ServicesImpl(){}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This compiles.

```
class ServicesImpl(ss :List[String])

def blacklist: List[String] = List("")
new ServicesImpl(blacklist)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want this

```
class ServicesImpl(foo: => List[String]) {}

def blacklist: List[String] = { }

val impl = new ServicesImpl(blacklist)
```